# ActionBar: how to stretch action view layout?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

The target is to show edit text in action bar stretched to the end of screen:

[image]

but the result is that action view layout looked wrapped:
[image]

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```

bar_search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

menu_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="search"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/bar_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what result you're expecting and what's wrong with your current result. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Have you tried putting the EditText inside a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout?

Comment: Hmm, thank you for suggestion, it works with RelativeLayout. I tried LinearLaout and FrameLaout with no success.

Comment: Okay good. I'll post this as an answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ActionBar` can behave a bit weirdly when it comes to ActionViews. For views slightly more complex than an icon, it's good to wrap any UI elements inside a `ViewGroup`.

Most times `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` do the trick. Try wrapping the `EditText` inside a `RelativeLayout`.